# could i have a regex when there are two or more keywords matched, it could return true?

Tags: regex, perl

there is a variable defined as below:

```
my $variable = "This is related to NSQ outage, it is being handled along with all other NSQ alarms. Network team is working on it.";
```

and some keywords are: `"is nsq this server"`.

could i have a regex when there are two or more keywords in `$variable`, it could return true?

example:

- when keywords are "is nsq server": true
- when keywords are "nsq machine server": false

**thanks, i think the question above has been solved.**

And i have a further question as below:

```
my $var="this is related to NSQ outage, and this is"; 

$var=~/((this|sth).*){2,}/, return true.
```

actually there is no 'sth' in `$var`, and `this` has two.

how to make regex return false in this situation?

Comment: Please create a new question if you have any follow-ups.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to find if at least two of these keywords are in the string and the order does not matter, you can do it with `grep` like this:

```
my $variable = "This is related to NSQ outage, it is being handled along with all other NSQ alarms. Network team is working on it.";
my @keywords = qw(is nsq server);

if ( ( grep { $variable =~ m/\b$_\b/i } @keywords ) >= 2) {
  print $variable;
}
```

The `grep` block will return a keyword if it is found in `$variable`. If the returned filtered list of keywords has at least two elements, your match is true.

Comment: Grep is a very nice solution for this.

Comment: @dognose: The question doesn't say that the order matter and I think we can presume that the fact that the order seems to matter in the example as just coincidence unless the question explicitly say otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a regular expression with a lot of `|` characters that capture all possible combinations of keyword pairs:

```
foreach my $k1 (@keywords) {
foreach my $k2 (@keywords) {
    next if $k1 eq $k2;
    push @expr, "\\b$k1\\b.*\\b$k2\\b";
}
}
$the_regex = join '|', @expr;

...
$variable =~ /$the_regex/i;
```

Comment: Nitpick: In strings, `\b` is the backspace character, not the word boundary. Either write the explicit lookaround `(?<!\w)$k1(?!\w)` etc. or use `qr//` quotes, or escape the backslash.

Comment: Good catch, amon. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The number of matches quantifier `{}` work for whole words as well as individual characters. When you want to match two or more of something you'd normally do:

```
/x{2,}/
```

For whole words (like your keywords) you can do:

```
/((is|nsq|this|server).*){2,}/
```

---

Examples:

```
# true:
$variable =~ /((is|nsq|server).*){2,}/; 

# false:
$variable =~ /((nsq|machine|server).*){2,}/;
```

Comment: Specifically what more do you want to know?

Comment: Wont that match the same word twice, eg `is is`. Also will match keywords within another word such as pissing.

Comment: thanks, this answer works. further question is: could the regex make the keywords unique? example:
my $var="this is related to NSQ outage, and this is";
$var=~/((this|sth).*){2,}/, return true.
actually there is no 'sth' in $var, and 'this' has two. 
how to make regex return false in this situation?

Comment: Ah, regex alone can't do that since it is merely a pattern matching state machine, not a grammar parsing engine. What you can do instead is to loop through the keywords and search for each keyword in the string and if a match happens twice (two keywords exist in the string) then return true.

Comment: Your question title specifies regex. The correct way to do what you want does not use regex at all but I'm reluctant to put it here because if I don't use regex then it is technically off topic to your question. Is a non-regex solution acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a look-ahead for each keyword you want matched, and a negative one for those to exclude:

```
^(?!.*\bDisallowThis\b)(?=.*\bMatchThis\b)(?=.*\bMatchThis\b).*$
```

---

Examples: 
Match any string with "is", "nsq" and "server":

```
^(?=.*\bis\b)(?=.*\bnsq\b)(?=.*\bserver\b).*$
```

Same, but disallow the keyword "machine":

```
^(?!.*\bmachine\b)(?=.*\bis\b)(?=.*\bnsq\b)(?=.*\bserver\b).*$
```

Match strings with "nsq", "machine" and "server":

```
^(?=.*\bnsq\b)(?=.*\bmachine\b)(?=.*\bserver\b).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need unique matches only - looks like a work for a hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $right = "This is related to NSQ server outage";
my $wrong = "server is a server server";
my $regex = qr(server|nsq)i;

print "right" if uniq_matches( $right, $regex ) > 1;
print "wrong" if uniq_matches( $wrong, $regex ) > 1; 

sub uniq_matches {
     my ($str, $regex) = @_;
     my %match;
     $match{$1}++ while $str =~ m/($regex)/g;
     return keys %match;
};
```